# ASP.NET MVC 2: Return Multiple Objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

```
List<Filter> filters;
List<Deal> deals;
using (DealDataContext db = new DealDataContext())
{
    XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<Request><ZipCode>92618</ZipCode></Request>");
    var result = db.SearchDeals(xmlTree);

    filters = result.GetResult<Filter>().ToList();
    deals = result.GetResult<Deal>().ToList();

}

return filters, deals;
```

What is the best way of returning more than one object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [**ViewModel**](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx) look for [best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices). Your case  -

```
public class DealViewModel
{
List<Filter> filters{get; set;}
List<Deal> deals{get; set;}
}
```

Function -

```
DealViewModel vm= new DeakViewModel();

using (DealDataContext db = new DealDataContext())
{
    XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse("<Request><ZipCode>92618</ZipCode></Request>");
    var result = db.SearchDeals(xmlTree);

    vm.filters = result.GetResult<Filter>().ToList();
    vm.deals = result.GetResult<Deal>().ToList();
    return vm;

}
```

Comment: Interesting. What I've got going on is a Repository that has a GetDeals function; the meat of that function is what I posted above. THEN I have a DealViewModel that just represents Deal and Filter get and set.

Comment: Well change the type of GetDeals to return a ViewModel or get the info by separate functions return lists of each filters and deals and then assign them to your ViewModel Object.

Comment: the first suggestion makes more sense. Returning the type of ViewModel. That way I only make one function call. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Create a class that wraps both objects up into one. Then return your wrapper object.

```
public class Wrapper
{
   List<Filter> Filters { get; set; }
   List<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Where should this wrapper go?

Comment: Okay, but I have a ViewModel... the issue is returning both filters and deals INTO the ViewModel.

Comment: @dcolumbus..Updated my response should help!