# ASP.NET MVC 3: Blog Posts's model Tags Binding Best Practices

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, model-binding

I have a model with BlogPost and Tag entities.

```
public class Tag
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Slug { get; set; }
}

public class BlogPost : ITaggable
{
    public BlogPost()
    {
        this.Tags = new List<Tag>();
    }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

On admin BlogPost edit page tags should be represented in one text input, separated by comma. Pretty much like StackOverflow tag's input.

It means serialization of ICollection to a string, and deseralization back to a collection.
I'm happy with default model binder, beside the Tags collection of BlogPost.

There are few options I know to handle it:

1. Custom Model Binder - with a need to override all BlogPost bindings - there are really a lot properties in a real BlogPost entity.
2. Create a text input not related to a BlogPost model, and get/set it's values using Form parameters. It requires more manual work too.
3. Something else....

How would you implement tags input for a blog post?

**UPDATE:**

For now I try this:

```
public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
public string TagsString { 
    get 
    { 
        var tags = Tags.Select(tg => tg.Name).ToArray();
        var res = string.Join(",", tags);
        return res;
    } 
    set 
    {
        var tags = value.Split(',');
        Tags = new List<Tag>();
        foreach (var tag in tags)
            Tags.Add(new Tag { Name = tag });
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect case to introduce a `ViewModel` between your view and your model.

A `ViewModel` will allow you to modify the representation of your data (split them in a string) for a specific view (it's a best practice to create one per view) without altering the integrity of your model.

Then, your controller will be in charge of the serialization/deserialization.

Here are a few articles talking about the need and the how of ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC applications:

- [ViewModel best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices)
- [ViewModel patterns](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx)
- [View Model pattern and AutoMapper](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2010/02/01/view-model-pattern-and-automapper-in-asp-net-mvc-applications.aspx)
- [ASP.NET MVC Tip #50 – Create View Models](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/04/13/asp.net-mvc-tip-50-ndash-create-view-models.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain the UI/UX to show them comma separated in a single text box.

As far as getting them as a collection in the controller, I personally would stick with the default modelbinder, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's the correct way.

I would do something akin to your #2, however I would use a `<select multiple="multiple">` so that there was 1 `<option selected="selected">TagName/Slug</option>` element for each tag.

As for maintaining the dependency / binding between the text box and the multi-select list, I would use [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) for this. Parse the commas in the text box, and update the (hidden) multi-select. When submitted to the controller, ignore the text box (or just don't make it part of your server-side viewmodel).