# MVC 3 how to disable data annotations in entity property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

```
public class Clubber
{
    public virtual int ObjectID { get; set;}
    public virtual User OwnerUser { get; set; }
    public virtual int BlackPoint { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ToSendSMS { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int ObjectID {get; set;}

    [Required]
    public virtual Permission Permission { get; set; }
}
```

and i try to make Dropdown list for the OwnerUser property by the ObjectID

```
@Html.DropDownList("OwnerUser.ObjectID", (SelectList)ViewBag.OwnerList)
```

and when I try to save its says that Permission Required
how can i disable the permission validation in this case?

Answer (score 1):

> I will suggest to use ViewModel which will have required fields to
>   render on UI and may be specific to you Controller - Action.

see this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices) on [best practices of using ViewModel](http://www.google.co.in/search?q=asp.net%20mvc%20viewmodel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=ng5&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&sclient=psy-ab&q=asp.net%20mvc%20viewmodel%20best%20practices&pbx=1&oq=asp.net%20mvc%20viewmodel%20best&aq=0&aqi=g1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=16414l17419l0l18494l5l4l0l1l1l1l649l1980l4-3.1l5l0&gs_l=serp.3.0.0.16414l17419l0l18495l5l4l0l1l1l1l649l1980l4-3j1l5l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f52c32652ac92f30&biw=1024&bih=578) -

Answer (score 0):

Use following in action.

```
[Bind(Exclude = "Permission")]
```

To exclude multiple attribute, you can do

```
 [Bind(Exclude = "attribute1,attribute2,attribute3")]
```

Comment: @dor: You can exclude more than properties using comman after each attribute name like [Bind(Exclude="OBJECTID,Permission")]