# Linq select join razor page display

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq, anonymous-types

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

   var result = from u in myContext.Users
             join g in myContext.Groups
             on u.gid equals g.id
             select new {
                 u.username,
                 g.name
             };

   return View(result );
}
```

This is the View

```
@model IEnumerable<eTravel1.Models.User>
...
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.username)
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.name)
..
```

The returned anonymous data is not compatible in the View.
I would really apreciate it if someone could give some advice. Thanks

Comment: for one thing, your razor script is looking for a "firstName" property, but your anonymous type uses "username" instead.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It should be model.username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a ViewModel Class like this:

```
public class UserViewModel{

    //class constructor
    public UserViewModel(String userName_p, String name_p){
         this.UserName = userName_p;
         this.Name = name_p;
    }

    //class attributes
    String UserName {get; set;}
    String Name {get; set;}
}
```

Create an object of that class:

```
var result = from u in myContext.Users
                 join g in myContext.Groups
                 on u.gid equals g.id
                 select new UserViewModel(
                     u.username,
                     g.name
                 );
```

And finally, pass this object to your view the same way:

```
//returning an IEnumerable<UserViewModel> data type
return View(result.AsEnumerable());
```

In your View, you should expect this exact same data type:

```
//change the UserViewModel to your complete namespace!
@model IEnumerable<UserViewModel>
```

I strongly recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices) stackoverflow question about the **"ViewModel Best Practices"**.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! When using 
select new UserViewModel{
                     u.username,
                     g.name
                 };
Cannot initialize type 'UserViewModel' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' message is displayed.
Also on view, how can I use two models? (since I use Users and Groups tables) Many thanks.

Comment: How are you defining the variable `var result`? Did you add the constructor to the class UserViewModel?

Comment: I just edited my answer, it should be `new UserViewModel( u.username, g.name );`... change { } for ( )

Comment: Yes, did the modifications, created the constructor. When the Index page is displayed, I get the following:The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[eTravel1.Controllers.UserViewModel]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[eTravel1.Models.User]'.

Comment: that is because your data types are different(the one you return in the controller and the one you receive in the view), I've just edited my answer again....

Comment: @AndreiSpatar did you solve it? If you did, can you mark the response as answer to your question please?

Comment: Thank for your help! I can sleep now.