# ASP.NET MVC 3 - FormCollection for a MultiSelectList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Here’s what I’m trying to do:

I’m attempting to collect multiple string values from a MultiSelectList, and upon HttpPost, create a new, separate database row corresponding to each value in that MultiSelectList for the associated Model.

In this case, I’m trying to create database entries for Service Location (for example, a plumber who services in Los Angeles, San Diego, and San Francisco). So he would go into my application and select State: California and then City: Los Angeles, San Diego, San Francisco… which would create three new records, each with a new SPServiceLocationID:

SPServiceLocationID: 1
SPCompanyAccountID: 4
State: 3
City: Los Angeles

Here is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace BidFetcher.Models
{
public class SPServiceLocation
{
public int SPServiceLocationID { get; set; }
public int SPCompanyAccountID { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "State")]
public string state { get; set; }

[Required]
[Display(Name = "Cities (select all that apply)")]
public string city { get; set; }

public virtual SPCompanyAccount SPCompanyAccount { get; set; }
}
}
```

Here is my Controller for generating the View, where I have no issue populating my MultiSelectList:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{

    ViewBag.sessionName = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyName"].ToString();

    var compID = HttpContext.Session["SPCompanyAccountID"].ToString();

    ViewBag.companyID = compID;

    ViewBag.state = new SelectList(simpleDB.simpleState, "simpleStateID", "simpleStateID");

    ViewBag.city = new MultiSelectList(simpleDB.simpleCity, "cityFull", "cityFull");

    return View();
}
```

Here is my View code that generates the MultiSelectList:

```
@Html.ListBox("city", ViewBag.city as MultiSelectList, new { @class = "chzn-select", data_placeholder = "Select cities..." })
```

And finally, here is my Controller data for posting to the database, which is the piece that I believe I need help:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(SPServiceLocation spservicelocation, FormCollection formValues)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        db.SPServiceLocation.Add(spservicelocation);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Create", "SPServiceLocation");
    }

return View(spservicelocation);
```

}

If someone can reference a tutorial for me, or provide some assistance, on how I might handle FormCollection in this scenario and modify my above HttpPost so that it’ll create multiple entires?

My knowledge s very basic, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tutorial that should help:

http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/

And you should look into making the move away from using ViewBag and into using ViewModels to handle your information (it will make your life a lot easier):

[ViewModel Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices)