# MVVM: ViewModel return instance of a model, or flatten VM List into Model List?

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a bit of a design issue, and I'm not sure the best approach to take.

I have a list of "Question" models that are loaded in. These questions are presented to the user, and as such are wrapped in a ViewModel class which records the users input.

The input is then used as part of an engine to produce various results. The inputs to this engine are generally lists of models that are used to process the end result.

My issue is that "Question" extends "Action", which is another model that is used in the engine, and it would make sense to make the engine process these objects together. However, the information gained from the user input is currently only kept on the QuestionViewModel.

What is the correct way to deal with this? Is it acceptable to have processes work with a mixture of Models and ViewModels? I have a few suggestions, but I don't know what the best design choice is:

- Have QuestionViewModel record the results on Question, and pass a list of Question to the engine.
- Pass the list of "QuestionViewModel" to the engine, but return an instance of the underlying "Question" and use that for processing

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `ViewModel` classes is to facilitate manipulation of your `Model` objects via a User Interface.

So typically you will be manipulating a `Question` instance via the `QuestionViewModel` interface and then pass the manipulated `Question` object back to the lower business logic layer (i.e. your processing engine).