# How to Pass Multiple Objects from Controller action to View in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How to pass multiple objects to view without using ViewData and ViewBag?

**Example:**

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RandomView()
{
   // Customer.
   var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
   List<CustomerDto> customersDto = new List<CustomerDto>();

   foreach (var customer in customers)
   {
      customersDto.Add(new CustomerDto() { 
      Id = customer.Id,
      Name = customer.Name
      });
   }

   // Reports.
   var Reports= _context.Reports.ToList();
   List<ReportsDto> reportsDto= new List<ReportsDto>();

   foreach (var report in reports)
   {
      reportsDto.Add(new ReportsDto() {
      Id = report.Id,
      Name = report.Name
      });
   }

   return View(); // How to Pass Both CustomerDto and reportDto ?
}
```

**I want to pass both `CustomerDto` & `reportDto` as a strongly type to a view. Is it Possible ?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664205/viewmodel-best-practices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide a model class for your view. In that view, you reference your model class. Make the two lists properties of your model class. See sample below:

```
public class RandomViewModel
{
    public List<CustomerDto> Customers { get; set; }
    public List<ReportDto> Reports { get; set; }
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RandomView()
{
   // Customer.
   var customers = _context.Customers.ToList();
   List<CustomerDto> customersDto = new List<CustomerDto>();

   foreach (var customer in customers)
   {
      customersDto.Add(new CustomerDto() { 
      Id = customer.Id,
      Name = customer.Name
      });
   }

   // Reports.
   var Reports= _context.Reports.ToList();
   List<ReportsDto> reportsDto= new List<ReportsDto>();

   foreach (var report in reports)
   {
      reportsDto.Add(new ReportsDto() {
      Id = report.Id,
      Name = report.Name
      });
   }

   var randomViewModel = new RandomViewModel() {
      Customers = customersDto,
      Reports = reportsDto
   };

   return View(randomViewModel);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap both types to some ViewModel class something like below:

```
public class CustomerData
{
    public List<CustomerDto> Customer { get; set; }
    public List<ReportsDto> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

and then pass to your view:

```
var customerData = new CustomerData() 
{
   Customer = customersDto,
   Reports = reportsDto
}
return View(customerData);
```

Comment: Why downvote this? That's how results are returned in MVC - create a ViewModel with all required data. It's the same as the other answers too

Answer (score 2):

**Way 1:**

Create a view model that has both properties & pass that view-model to view

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public List<CustomerDto> Customers {get;set;}
   public List<ReportsDto> Reports {get;set;}
}
```

**Way 2:**

Use Tuple & pass that Tuple object to view

```
var tupleModel = new Tuple<List<CustomerDto>, List<ReportsDto>>(GetCustomers(), GetReports());  
return View(tupleModel);
```

*In view*

Make the view strongly typed with Tuple

```
@model Tuple <List<CustomerDto>, List <ReportsDto>>
```

Access the both objects using Item1 & Item2 properties

```
@Model.Item1
@Model.Item2
```